# MediaPlayer - can't find path of sdcard on real device

Tags: android, media-player, sd-card

On my code I use:

```
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/mymusic/asong.mp3";

    try {
        mp.setDataSource(filePath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mp.start();
```

And on the emulator the song.mp3 is played normally. But when I test it on my real device, it gives an error (-38, 0). That means it can not find the path of the song. I connect the usb cable, go to my Computer, GT-I8260 and paste the folder "mymusic" (that contains asong.mp3) under "Card" folder (where an empty folder named "LOST.DIR" is also placed). But why doesn't it work? Thanks a lot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it's card but at least

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/mymusic/asong.mp3";
```

is enough.

Make sure it exists because you may not have the folder created before.

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/mymusic");

if (!f.exists()) { f.mkdirs(); }
```

also make sure that it's not mounted while writing, since it may happen that it is not accessable at all.

Also revalidate that you have setupted the manifests permission to read/write the external storage

Comment: Tested it and gives the same error. I do use  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> and <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> normally on the AndroidManifest.xml. It keeps running on emulator tho =/

Comment: have you removed the getPath()? have you using a mkDirs() before? Have you tried before?

Comment: I didn't use mkDirs() before. I tried both removing getPat()h and using mkDirs() and it gives same error